# Скрипт на Raspberry Pi запускается два раза при автозагрузке

Tags: telegram-bot, raspberry-pi, vnc

На *Raspberry pi* есть **телеграмм бот**, который должен **автоматически запускаться при запуске системы** *Raspberry Pi Os*; **Однако** так как я использую *VNC Server* и *VNC Viewer* для управления *Raspberry Pi* удаленно, скрипт который запускает бота, по неведомым мне причинам, запускается и в **системе**, и на **VNC клиенте**. Из-за этого **бот выдает ошибку**, что запущенно несколько ботов и поэтому **перестает нормально работать**.

**Что нужно сделать, чтобы бот запускался только на VNC сервере и был виден при входе с VNC клиента?**

Файл автозагрузки **Start_BOT.desktop** находится в этой папке **/home/pi/.config/autostart/Start_BOT.desktop**

*Его содержимое:*

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=BotServer
Exec=lxterminal -e /home/pi/TelegramBots/Bot_Linux/Start_Bot
Icon=lxterminal
Type=Application
Categories=Utility;
```

*Фото ошибки с VNC клиента (оно идентично ошибке в системе):*
[image: Фото ошибки]

Comment: От какого пользователя стартует VNC-сервер?

Comment: Если не ошибаюсь он запускается от пользователя pi

Comment: Ну вот вам и ответ. Один раз при запуске сервера, потому что автозапуск, второй раз когда заходит пользователь, потому что автозапуск.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Итак проблему я решил немного другим способом из-за новых обстоятельств, которые теперь вынуждают меня перезагружать бота после его закрытия.

Для начала я установил ***xterm*** (так как он показался мне удобней):

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install xterm
```

Затем я установил ***systemd***:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install systemd
```

**[!] Учитывайте, что файлы с расширением *.desktop* и *.service* должны находится там где они находятся у меня. Остальные месторасположения файлов зависят только от вас [!]**

После этого мною было создано **2 скрипта** и **1 файл** с расширением ***.service***, и **1 файл** с расширением ***.desktop***.

**[1] Первый** скрипт запускал скрипт, который открывал бота в новом окне именно на VNC, а не в системе. *Его код:*

```
#!/bin/bash
DISPLAY=:1 xterm -e /home/pi/TelegramBots/Bot_Linux/Startup_Bot
```

**Не забываем сделать файл исполняемым!** C помощью команды в терминале:
`chmod +x /home/pi/TelegramBots/Bot_Linux/Startup_Bot`

**[2] Затем** идёт файл `start_bot.service`, который я создал по пути `/etc/systemd/system/`.
Команда для создания файла: `sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/start_bot.service` 
*В файле прописываем:*

```
[Unit]
Description=Bot Startup Script
After=graphical.target
After=network.target

[Service]
Environment=XAUTHORITY=/home/pi/.Xauthority
DISPLAY=:1
User=pi
Type=idle
ExecStart=/home/pi/TelegramBots/Bot_Linux/Startup_Bot.sh
User=pi
Environment=XAUTHORITY=/home/pi/.Xauthority
RestartSec=10
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=graphical.target
```

После этого выходим из ***nano*** нажатием **Ctrl+X**, затем жмём **Y** и потом нажимаем **Enter**.

**[3] Потом создаем скрипт который активирует нашего demon.** Для этого создаем скрипт  с названием `ReloadDemons` и в моем случае по такому месторасположению
`/home/pi/TelegramBots/ReloadDemons`.

 *Содержимое скрипта:*

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl enable start_bot
sudo systemctl start start_bot
```

**Не забываем сделать файл исполняемым!** C помощью команды в терминале:
`chmod +x /home/pi/TelegramBots/ReloadDemons`

**[4] После этого** я создал файл автозагрузки с расширением ***.desktop*** который запускал скрипт описанный выше.
*Его месторасположение*: `/home/pi/.config/autostart/reboot_demons.desktop`
*И его содержимое*:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Restart Demons
Exec=/home/pi/TelegramBots/ReloadDemons
StartupNotify=false
```

**Всё сохраняем и выполняем команду `sudo reboot`**

***Надеюсь мой ответ помог кому то, кто сталкивался с подобной проблемой!***

*Ссылки которые помогли мне решить эту проблему:*
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/617201/is-it-possible-to-have-systemd-open-a-program-running-in-a-clean-terminal-automa
[Как автоматически перезапустить бота в случае ошибки?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1111078/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B8)

Comment: `установил systemd` — мягко говоря, нецелесообразное решение. типа «на моём запорожце плохо работала педаль газа, поэтому я заменил двигатель на вертолётный, и теперь газ отлично регулируется с помощью рукоятки справа от кресла пилота».

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, спасибо за ваш комментарий. Я просто являюсь новичком в linux и искал ответа на форумах, но по всей видимости нашёл не самое оптимальное решение. Что в таком случае вы бы порекомендовали сделать?

Comment: да кроме «разберитесь с тем, что у вас там происходит» ничего и не придумывается: 1. что такое «запускается в системе» — абсолютно не ясно. эмулятор терминала не сможет запуститься без подключения к x-сессии. а откуда она у вас там берётся? 2. что такое «запускается на vnc-клиенте» — абсолютно не ясно. ведь vnc-клиент умеет лишь подключаться к vnc-серверу, получать от него картинку и отправлять информацию от устройств ввода. 3. реализаций vnc-клиентов, как и vnc-серверов, существует значительно больше одной, а у вас не указано ни то, ни другое. // это так, для начала.

Comment: 4. зачем вам эмулятор терминала, кстати, тоже совершенно не ясно. мультиплексора было бы более чем достаточно. ведь самому вашему скрипту вряд ли нужен доступ к x-сессии. 5. отсюда и следующий вопрос: зачем вам вообще vnc, если текстовой информации, насколько я понимаю, более чем достаточно? // и так далее и т.п.

Comment: 6. есть подозрение, что и мультиплексор терминала будет перебором: вам что, реально требуется интерактивное общение с процессом, интерпретирующим ваш скрипт?